# how to resolve Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am working on automation system (JSP servlet + Spring MVC). in this system has JSTL forEach loop for iterate list of objects (currently this list has 1833 items) and put that item to HTML select option.

Here is my loop.

```
<c:forEach items="${REFERENCES}" var="listware">
  <option value=""></option>
  </c:forEach>
```

when i open the particular jsp page, it gives "**Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**". when I delete one of item from database, error is disappeared. how can i solve this matter?

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded